# Populate array from while loop to return PHP

Tags: php, arrays, return

Hi im trying to populate an array with indexes like 'user1' and 'score1' to return to a function.

My Code: It comes up with unindentified variable errors

```
$query = 'select * from users order by score desc';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$highscore = array();
$count = '0';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $count++;         
    $highscore = array('user' . $count => $row['username'], 'score' . $count => $row['score']);
}

return $highscore;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use numeric values when you want to use them.. You used a string representation of zero (`'0'`)

```
$count = 0;
$highscore = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{       
    $count++; 
    $highscore['user' . $count] = $row['username'];
    $highscore['score' . $count] = $row['score'];
}
```

Comment: Won't that give an array of arrays?

Comment: @gar - true true - my keyboard got away from me for a second there :P

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted 'high score' you might want to use max and just return 1 row.

Comment: What if it is the users own personal high score?

Comment: @lix the query could easily be altered 'SELECT max(score) FROM users WHERE username = 'lix' but he has said that he requires it for a function, presumably to populate a table.